# Cucumber: Scenario Outline reusing examples table

Tags: java, cucumber, integration-testing

I have a few tests like below:

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numebrs
  Given two numbers <number_1> and <number_2>
  When I add them
  Then Result is <number_3>

  Examples:
    |number_1|number_2|number_3|
    |2       |3       |5       |
    |1       |2       |3       |

Scenario Outline: Update two numebrs
  Given two numbers <number_1> and <number_2>
  When I update them
  Then Result is <number_3>

  Examples:
    |number_1|number_2|number_3|
    |2       |3       |5       |
    |1       |2       |3       |
```

For each test I should add the same table **Examples**.

Is any way to extract this table to use the same one for all tests?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution that comes to my mind is combining both scenarios, extracting details to the examples table. So it would look like:

```
| number_1 | number_2 | operation | result |
```

You have another possibility.

```
Scenario: Add two numebrs
Given I have the matrix of numbers
When I add them
Then I would have the resulting vector.

Scenario: Update two numebrs
Given I have the matrix of numbers
When I update them
Then I would have the resulting vector.
```

Where "the matrix of numbers" and "the resulting vector" go to step defs file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you can move examples in external file and use it with one or more scenario. With qaf your feature file may look like below:

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numebrs
  Given two numbers <number_1> and <number_2>
  When I add them
  Then Result is <number_3>

  Examples::{'datafile':'resources/testdata.txt'}

Scenario Outline: Update two numebrs
  Given two numbers <number_1> and <number_2>
  When I update them
  Then Result is <number_3>
  Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.txt'}
```

And your datafile will look like:

```
  #col.separator=|
  number_1|number_2|number_3
  2|3|5       
  1|2|3
```

Above is example of csv (charter separated values)  data provider with | as seperator. You also can use different data providers to provide data from any of excel/xml/json/database.

EDIT: [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber) has [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) support with cucumber that can be used with Cumber 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the cucumber runner, you can not use QAF as it works with TestNG. Also I think that switching to QAF just to use data providers is overkill.

You might want to use qaf-cucumber as stated by user861594 (it offers the choice to use the cucumber runner and all QAF BDD2 features), but for the moment the plugin is in beta; I tested it and it is buggy (placeholders for examples not working, incompatible with pretty). Hopefully a stable release will come soon.

The solution I chose is in principle the same as what qaf-cucumber does: **overwrite the Gherkin compiler coming as a transitive dependency with cucumber**, and only change how it parses scenario outline so examples can be extracted from .csv/.txt files. To do so you have to create the class `gherkin.pickles.Compiler`. This is the same path than the real gherkin compiler, so this will overwrite the reference to it. Then you can copy/paste the code of the real gherkin compiler and modify it to suit your needs.

Of course this not a perfect solution. For example, if the path to the gherkin compiler changes after a version upgrade, the path to your compiler will have to change too.

**Note**: For the moment, qaf-cucumber does not work with the pretty plugin because pretty parses the scenario again before printing it, but not with the `Compiler` class of gherkin. This is done in the class `io.cucumber.core.plugin.TestSourcesModel`, so to make pretty work you may also have to overwrite this class. I did both and it works fine so far.